# Bootstrap 4.1.3 Nested Tables Colspan problem

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having problems with colspan in a nested table. I've tried encapsulating the table in a div. Still nothing seems to work. What I want to happen is for the nested table to open across the length of the parent table.  See JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nikropht/0L652f1t/1/

```
                                <tr>
                                <td id="order1000" class="card-body table-responsive collapse" colspan="6">
                                    
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Product</th>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th>Price</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Video 1</td>
                                                <td>Desc 1</td>
                                                <td>$20.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Video 2</td>
                                                <td>Desc 2</td>
                                                <td>$5.00</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                        
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

Comment: Try remove `table-responsive` from your `td`

Comment: That was it. Thx.

Comment: Glad to hear that, I'll add an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove `table-responsive` from your `td`